# C++ How to set pixel colors

Tags: c++, winapi, c++17, pixel

I created a code which change a certain pixels on the screen but when i want to change more pixels the performance of program will slow down.
You will see glitches and it's not that pretty as it should be.

**Question:** 
**How can i inprove performance of the code.**  
*If I want to change more pixel or eventually all pixels on the screen. 

I thought about using SETBITMAPBITS but I'm not sure how to it works. I have no experience with it.* 
Is there any other solution?

Example of my code: < Console app >

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x601
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HDC dng = GetDC(NULL);
    
    while (true)
        for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j <= 500; j++)
                SetPixel(dng, i, j, RGB(0, 0, 255));

    ReleaseDC(NULL, dng);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Don't draw onto `GetDC(NULL)`; create you own window instead. Use `SetDIBitsToDevice` or `StretchDIBits` to set multiple pixels at once.

Comment: If the goal is to draw a sold blue rectangle, use `FillRect` to draw the whole thing in one call.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Hi thanks for anware it forks good but there are still some glitches.

Comment: @YakovGalka Thanks for answare. I tryied to do it but i had truble with implementing and creating BITMAP in BITMAPINFO. If you have any example code it will help me. Thanks

Comment: @8888 there's no `BITMAP` in `BITMAPINFO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to draw outside a window.

Every time you `SetPixel` you send a WM_PAINT message, which repaints the whole window.
That dramatically slows down your program. What you should do is use GDI, GDI+ or Direct2D to create a bitmap or a rectangle to then draw it at once.

Drawing outside a window is never a good idea. You have no control on what you just drew, and it will disappear when something interrupts it.

If you want a blue block without a title bar, create a layered window, then create a rectangle and draw it.

Microsoft's documentation might not be a tutorial, but it is informative.

Here is the Direct2D documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/getting-started-with-direct2d

And here is how to create a layered window:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows

Edit:
Comment said that `SetPixel` doesn't send `WM_PAINT`. What I am saying is `SetPixel` repaints the window.

Comment: Hi thanks for answare. That is probably the right think what I'm looking for. I will check it.

Comment: `SetPixel` doesn't send `WM_PAINT`.